# omniauth 0.2.6 with multiple domain names

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using different domain names for my web application (www.example.heroku.com, www.example2.com and www.example3.com). Authentication is with Omniauth 0.2.6

If I want my users to authenticate via Facebook, I need a different Facebook app account for each domain name, so a different app ID and secret key.

When defining the app ID and secret key in the omniauth initializer (provider :facebook, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET"), how can I:

- define multiple app ids/keys
- or define the ids/keys conditionally to the current domain name

I've been trying all day without success...

Comment: Solution : https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Dynamic-Providers/eb14c359a585a9e8e445a9a8ea7c46d8fb0e7358

Answer (score 2):

The setup for this has changed in the [setup phase](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Setup-Phase) of Omniauth 1.1.0

You now have to set this up in your omniauth.rb

```
provider_keys = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'provider_keys.yml'))

SETUP_PROC = lambda do |env| 
    env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_id]      = provider_keys[Rails.env]['facebook'][server_name]['consumer_key'] 
    env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_secret]  = provider_keys[Rails.env]['facebook'][server_name]['consumer_secret']
end

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, setup: SETUP_PROC
end
```

and your provider_keys.yml will look something like this

```
development:
  facebook:
    www.example.heroku.com:
      consumer_key: 'xxxxxxxx'
      consumer_secret: 'xxxxxxxx'
    www.example.com:
      consumer_key: 'xxxxxxx'
      consumer_secret: 'xxxxxxx'
```